# PdfBox write hindi characters in pdf file

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

I tried many things to write hindi characters using Apache PdfBox but seems its existing issue in the library.

I tried many font files available, Can someone really help me out in this.

I tried following :

```
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();    
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(page);
    PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF( doc, new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Data\\fonts\\dn.ttf")));   
    font.setFontEncoding(new WinAnsiEncoding());   
    PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream( doc, page, true, false );   
    content.setFont(font, 10);   
    content.beginText();

    content.moveTextPositionByAmount( 200, 100 );   
    content.drawString( "हिंदी" ); // Writing word "Hindi" in hindi language.  
    content.endText();   
    content.close();
    doc.save( new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\testOutput1.pdf")));   
    doc.close();
```

Comment: You set the font encoding to `WinAnsiEncoding`. This automatically restricts the font to a character set similar to Latin-1 / ISO 8859-1, i.e. Western European letters. Thus, your `"हिंदी"` string drawing argument won't find any match in the font...

Comment: Complex scripts are not properly supported in PDFBox. There is an issue but it has stalled.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4189

Answer (score 1):

I think this cannot be done using PdfBox as there are lot of issues with it.
I tried many fonts and the encoding types of PdfBox but failed to write in Hindi.

At the end I tried it in Node Js express pdfmaker() which converts Html to PDF, However I had issues on my Linux server and I installed appropriate ttf font and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me in PDFBox.
The trick here is to use non-unicode string instead of unicode string.

Use Kruti Dev Font given in below link.
Then convert your unicode string to non-unicode string.
And finally use that converted string in your code.

That means replace this like

```
content.drawString( "हिंदी" ); // Writing word "Hindi" in hindi language.
```

With this line

```
content.drawString( "fganh" ); // Writing word "Hindi" in hindi language.
```

[Convert Unicode (Mangal) To Kruti Dev Font](https://indiatyping.com/index.php/font-converter/unicode-to-krutidev-font-converter)